# How to write macro for Finding match for each text value separated by comma in single cell with other cell values and return the matched values

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns "Tag Name" and "keywords" in my input sheet, and the Keywords column has each cell with multiple values separated by comma.

I would like to compare  each string value in a cell with other cell values in the Keywords column and if there is a matched instance between the cells return the output in specified format as mentioned below.

**My Input will be like below:**

```
Tag Name    Keywords

Product1 -  Product,System,Features

Product2 -  Application,Product,System

Product3 -  Application,Apps,System
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Tag Name                        Keywords

Product1,Product2           -   Product

Product1,Product2,Product3  -   System

Product2,Product3           -   Application
```

Input and Output Screenshot
[image]

```
Public Function DupeWord(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
Dim dictStr1Words As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim colDupeWords As New Collection

'Set up the Regular Expression
Dim oRegExp As New RegExp
Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
Dim oMatch As Match
With oRegExp
  .Global = True
  .MultiLine = True
  .Pattern = "([\w']+)"   'Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to '[A-Za-z0-9_']'
  Set oMatches = .Execute(str1)
End With

'Add each word in Str1 into a Scripting.Dictionary
For Each oMatch In oMatches
    If Not dictStr1Words.Exists(oMatch.Value) Then
        dictStr1Words.Add oMatch.Value, 0
    End If
Next

Set oMatches = oRegExp.Execute(str2)

'Check to see if any of the words found in Str2 was in Str1 using the Scripting.Dictionary function Exists
For Each oMatch In oMatches
    If dictStr1Words.Exists(oMatch.Value) Then
        colDupeWords.Add oMatch.Value  'Add any dups to a collection
    End If
Next

'If there are any dup words in the collection, join them up as a comma separated list, otherwise return "No Matches!"
If colDupeWords.Count > 0 Then
    DupeWord = JoinStringCollection(colDupeWords, ", ")
Else
    DupeWord = "No Matches!"
End If

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function JoinStringCollection(colStrings As Collection, strDelimiter As String) As String
'This function joins a collection with a delimiter so that there is no need to lop off a trailing or leading delimiter
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim i As Long

    If colStrings.Count > 0 Then
        strOut = colStrings.Item(1)
    End If

    If colStrings.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To colStrings.Count
            strOut = strOut & strDelimiter & colStrings.Item(i)
        Next
    End If

    JoinStringCollection = strOut
End Function
```

In excel sheet i am calling function =Dupeword(A1,A2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, questions should include a specific programming issue where you expected an outcome but got something else, like an error. It's not a code service or tutorial. If you describe what you have tried so far, maybe someone can help you.

Comment: I have tried below code

Comment: Where is your code @umamaheswari ?

Comment: i have mentioned the code i tried in my description, with this i am able to compare only 2 cells, but i want to compare each string value in a cell with values in all other cells and return the Tag name for matched string value

Comment: `Split` and `Join`? I know it is kind of obvious, but you never know, it just may work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a macro that can  reproduce what you want.

- I use a dictionary to make a list of the unique keywords.
- Each item of that dictionary is another dictionary of the associated tag names
- The output is only those primary dictionary items where the secondary dictionary contains more than one item
- I use the VBA functions `Split` and `Join` to break apart and reform the comma separated lists.
- I use early-binding for the dictionary object, finding it easier to code with the advantage of intellisense.  But you can easily change it to late-binding, as you have in your code above, if you prefer.

**EDIT:** *Code edited to allow for comma or `OR` as a delimiter.  The `Join` will always be done with a comma*

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub TagsForKeywords()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dKeyWords As Dictionary, dTagName As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim sDelim As String


Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 7)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

Set dKeyWords = New Dictionary
    dKeyWords.CompareMode = TextCompare

    For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)

    'Find delimiter
    sDelim = ","
    If InStr(1, vSrc(I, 2), " OR ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then _
        sDelim = " OR "

        V = Split(vSrc(I, 2), sDelim) 'array of keywords
        For Each W In V
            sKey = Trim(W)
            Set dTagName = New Dictionary
                dTagName.CompareMode = TextCompare
            If Not dKeyWords.Exists(sKey) Then
                dTagName.Add vSrc(I, 1), vSrc(I, 1)
                dKeyWords.Add sKey, dTagName
            Else
                Set dTagName = dKeyWords(sKey)
                If Not dTagName.Exists(vSrc(I, 1)) Then _
                    dTagName.Add vSrc(I, 1), vSrc(I, 1)
                Set dKeyWords(sKey) = dTagName
            End If
        Next W
    Next I

'Output results
' Only for Tags that have duplicate keywords

'So Output a row only if there are multiple Products tagged
I = 0
For Each V In dKeyWords.Keys
    If dKeyWords(V).Count > 1 Then I = I + 1
Next V

ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To 2)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Tag Name"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Keywords"

I = 0
For Each V In dKeyWords.Keys
 If Not dKeyWords(V).Count = 1 Then
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 2) = V
    W = dKeyWords(V).Keys
    vRes(I, 1) = Join(W, ",")
  End If
Next V

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

**Multiple delimiters example**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton Ron.. its working exactly as expected... Thank you very much for the detailed steps...

Comment: Can we pass multiple separators in this line "V = Split(vSrc(I, 2), ",")

Comment: if we hard code some separators like  Comma(,) , Semi column (;) etc. Macro should run based on the separator available in the excel data. Could you please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: @umamaheswari What are possible separators? Will there only be one type per string? When `Join`ing, do we use the same as found? All can be done. Just need answers to create code.

Comment: @umamaheswari What are possible separators? Will there only be one type per string? Can a separator ever appear within the desired text substring? When Joining, do we use the same as found? All can be done. Just need answers to create code.

Comment: Possible separators are "," and "OR" between keywords. Yes, only Either one of this will be used per string. If i manually change from , to OR its working fine i just want to know if we hard code both separators so i dont need to manually change everytime?

Comment: Product,System,Features

Comment: Product OR System OR Features

Comment: @umamaheswari For just the two, it is easy enough to detect.  And I will assume that the `OR` is upper case and surrounded by spaces.  I will edit my answer

Comment: these Separators will not appear within the desired text string

Comment: Yes OR is uppercase

Answer (score 0):

you could try this sub

```
Sub m()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim kwd As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = TextCompare
        For Each cell In Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            For Each kwd In Split(Replace(Replace(cell.Value,"OR",",")," ",""), ",")
                .Item(kwd) = .Item(kwd) & cell.Offset(, -1).Value & " "
            Next
        Next
        Range("E1:F1").Value = Range("A1:B1").Value
        For Each kwd In .Keys
            If UBound(Split(.Item(kwd), " ")) > 1 Then
                Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 2).Value = Array(Replace(Trim(.Item(kwd)), " ", ","), kwd)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @umamaheswari, any feedback?

Comment: Thank you, this code is working fine, only issue is case sensitivity, Its matching keyword if case is matching only.

Comment: your question didn't mention any case sensitivity issue. so that shouldn't be a criteria to choose which answer to mark as the solution with. while I'm always preferring a much shorter (and much more maintainable) code instead of a much longer (and much less maintainable) one...

Comment: anyhow, should you ever reach any sensitivity to short code, you may consider edited answer (one line added) to get rid of case sensitivity

Comment: I agree.. its working fine now.. when i tried changing the separator from comma to "OR", its giving different results

Comment: i know this is also not mentioned in my question, just giving my findings, i have tried keywords with separator "OR" as this is one of my business case-  Product OR System OR Features

Comment: @DisplayName For sure your code is shorter. And I like your technique. But maintainability is a relative issue, depending on familiarity with the techniques being used. In addition, I suspect that your code will run slower, and that this would be an issue on large data sources.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, what are you suspecting that from?

Comment: Added “OR” handling.

Comment: Your accessing of the worksheet multiple times.  Try your macro on a data source of 100,000 lines, for example.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, c’mon: we both know it’s only a matter of using an array to store range values (and adding some 2 or three code lines). But you must be right: umanaheswari didn’t choose this solution and NOBODY upvoted it...

Comment: @DisplayName I used to revel in short code, back in my days of machine language programming. Unfortunately, unless very well documented, when I reviewed the code a month later, it would take a while to figure out what I had done.  Now, with faster machines and cheap memory, I try for code that runs quickly, but is also self-documenting with minimal comments. In this forum, where possible, I also like to present code that is easily scalable to large data sources, as that has been a frequent issue by the posters. At the end, it comes down to style and personal preferences.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I must repeat myself _"you must be right: umanaheswari didn’t choose this solution and NOBODY upvoted it... "